# Cucumber - how to get scenario tag that is currently being executed

Tags: webdriver-io

I have scenario with multiple tags. For example, @registration, @smoke, @core.
I have a configuration file (test.conf.js file) in which I set targeted tests to be run like this:

```
cucumberOpts: {

    tags: ['@registration', '~@WIP']

}
```

Running this configuration will only run scenarios with @registration tag.
With this I can get and iterate through all scenario tags (in this case @registration, @smoke, @core):

```
beforeScenario: function (scenario) {

    tags = scenario.getTags();

    tags.forEach(function (scenarioTagItem) { ... });
}
```

My question is how to get in the above function the tag that the test is currently running against? So how to recognize that currently running tag is @registration? Sort of to recognize it as an active tag?
Please help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just called `this.cucumberOpts.tags` because it was in the same file and build my logic further on that. Stupid overlook from my side :/
Even better way to do it is `browser.options.cucumberOpts.tags`